# How do I install a custom build of asp.net vnext KRuntime?

Tags: asp.net-core

I [built the KRuntime](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ctaggart/kruntime/build/0.0.1) using AppVeyor. Its [artifacts](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ctaggart/kruntime/build/0.0.1/artifacts) from `artifacts\build\*.nupkg` are in its [nuget feed](https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/kruntime-9bonrgwx3sm6). How do I install this KRuntime build using the [Version Manager](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/version-manager)?

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the package to your local machine, then:

`kvm install KRE-svr50-x64.1.0.0-t140627040749.nupkg`

Your milage may vary. I get this output:

`C:\Users\chris\Downloads>kvm install KRE-svr50-x64.1.0.0-t140627040749.nupkg
Unpacking to C:\Users\chris\.kre\packages\temp
Installing to C:\Users\chris\.kre\packages\KRE-svr50-x64.1.0.0-t140627040749
Cannot find KRE-svr50-x86.1.0.0-t140627040749, do you need to run 'kvm install 1.0.0-t140627040749'?`